# In X-Men: Apocalypse why was the jail security so poorly armed?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

In X-Men: Apocalypse, when...

> Jean, Cyclops, and Nightcrawler go to save Mystique, Beast, etc, and find and free Wolverine

...they are spotted on camera and security arrives to apprehend them. A few hours before, they were using more effective weapons, but now only have conventional firearms.

Why weren't they armed the same as previously?

Comment: I made some pretty extensive changes to your grammar, Eskignax, but I think the essence of the question is retained. Feel free to edit further or roll back if you like.

Comment: I wondered about exactly this question when I saw the film. It might be worth mentioning in the question that the weapons they used previously knocked out dozens of people (all mutants) by projecting some sort of visible energy field. I doubt there's an explanation for this yet, unless those weapons were some technology from the comics...

Comment: I am afraid that the only answer of this question is 'fan service'… :(